# How to change TextBox BackColor In VB6?

Tags: user-interface, vb6

I am working on VB6 environment.
I have a textbox whereby i need to change its background color based on my setting.inf file.

```
TextBox.BackColor = "&H00C0FFFF&"
```

I wanted to change it to this yellow color value(&H00C0FFFF&) but unable to get it working.
Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

resolved.

The value cannot be a string.

```
TextBox.BackColor = &H00C0FFFF&
```

Comment: Yeah, the `&H` at the front of the number is saying that the number between the two ampersands is hexadecimal (the closing ampersand is optional, since a space is also considered a terminating character). Easy to confuse this as a string, since there are a bunch of alpha characters in it. All of [these type characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) in VB.Net apply equally to VB6.